# Regex - Match from Character to Character only if a specified String is in between the Group

Tags: regex

I want to match the string between two ")" characters only if a specified word is found in the string.

For example, consider this block of text:

```
...Milwaukee 2 (FINAL) Arizona 6   Chicago Cubs 5 (BOT 6TH) NY Mets 4   Colorado 5 (FINAL) Detroit...
```

with the specified word being "Colorado". The language being used is Kustom, but for simplicity, consider the language to be javascript with lookbehinds.

I would like to match:

```
 NY Mets 4   Colorado 5 (FINAL)
```

I tried: `(?<=\)).*?(Colorado).*?(?:\))` but it returns a match starting from the first ")" to the one after Colorado.

Comment: I solved it by `(?<=\))[\w ]*?(?=Colorado).*?(?:\))`

Comment: I'd rather suggest using negated character classes, [`\)([^()]*Colorado[^)]*)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/KPqgRR/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Staring from a word boundary this captures:

- the word characters and spaces previous to the target word Colorado
- the target word Colorado
- all subsequent word characters, spaces and opening brackets
- the closing bracket

  ```
  \b[\w\s]*?Colorado[\w\s\(]*?\)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

try this `(?!\s).*?Colorado.*?(?:\))`

```js
s = `...Milwaukee 2 (FINAL) Arizona 6   Chicago Cubs 5 (BOT 6TH) 
   NY Mets 4   Colorado 5 (FINAL) Detroit...`

m = s.match(/(?!\s).*?Colorado.*?(?:\))/gm)
console.log(m[0]);
```

`

Comment: apologies, it should be assumed that the information is all on one line so this answer won't work